# How to use QueryDslJpaRepository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In my current project setup I'm defining repositories as:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer> {
}
```

The `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` provides additional `findAll` methods which return e.g. an `Iterable`.
It e.g. does *not* contain a method to only specify an `OrderSpecifier`.

I just came across the `QueryDslJpaRepository` which contains more variants of these `Predicate` and `OrderSpecifier` aware methods, and also return `List`s instead of `Iterable`s.

I wonder why `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` is limited and if it is possible to use `QueryDslJpaRepository` methods?

Comment: [QueryDslJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QueryDslJpaRepository.java) is an implementation of [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.java) and does not provide any additional methods.  The later does contain a method that takes only a `vararg` array of `Specifier` s.

Comment: Probably my confusion is coming from the fact that e.g. `public List<T> findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>... orders) {` is not part of current Spring Data Commons release.

Comment: I've upgraded to latest spring Data Commons 1.10.0.RC1 and Spring Data JPA 1.8.0.RC1 and they include the method(s) I mentioned.

Comment: Correct, but what I was saying is that Spring Data Commons and Spring Data JPA are always in sync, except for a very short period of time on the development branches.  So, the scenario mentioned in your post about one containing more methods than the other would not arise.  For example, the current Spring Data JPA version is 1.7.2 which uses Spring Data Commons 1.9.2 and if you check those two out, you will find that the two components are in sync.

Comment: Only the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` return an Iterable and the `QueryDslJpaRepository` a List. To actually use a list I've to convert the Iterable manually to a list or probably better override the method in my (base) repository interface.

Comment: The `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` uses `Iterable` because it is implemented in multiple Spring Data projects and [not all stores can guarantee returning a `List`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-126).  You could either use the workaround mentioned in the link or do `List<Order> orders = (List<Order>) orderRepository.findAll(Order.MySpecifier)` since we know that the JPA implementation does return a `List`.

Comment: Yes I understand the reasoning; will post my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a custom BaseRepository already so It was easy to make sure my repositories use the `List` variant (instead of `Iterable`) using:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    @Override
    List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate);

    @Override
    List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort);

    @Override
    List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);

    @Override
    List<T> findAll(OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);
}
```

Note that my commnent reagarding missing methods in `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

QueryDslJpaRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository

SimpleJpaRepository is used when you want to [adding custom behavior to all repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories). It takes three steps to do so:

Step 1: Create an interface (eg CustomRepository) that extends JpaRepository, then add your own interface methods

Step 2: Create a class (eg CustomRepositoryImpl) that implements your CustomRepository, which naturally requires you to supply concrete method implementations to each and every method defined in not only CustomRepository but also JpaRepository as well as JpaRepository's ancestor interfaces. It'd be a tedious job, so Spring provide a SimpleJpaRepository concrete class to do that for you. So all you need to do is to make CustomRepositoryImpl to extend SimpleJpaRepository and then only write concrete method for the method in your own CustomRepository interface.

Step 3: make CustomRepositoryImpl the new base-class in the jpa configuration (either in xml or JavaConfig)

Similarly, QueryDslJpaRepository is the drop-in replacement for SimpleJpaRepository when your CustomRepository extends not only JpaRepository but also QueryDslPredicateExecutor interface, to add QueryDsl support to your repositories.

I wish Spring Data JPA document made it clear what to do if someone is using QueryDslPredicateExecutor but also wants to add his/her own customized methods. It took me some time to figure out what to do when the application throws errors like "No property findAll found for type xxx" or "No property exists found for type xxx".

Answer (score 0):

Check your Predicate import in Service, for my case it was because auto import brings `import java.util.function.Predicate;` instead of `import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;`. This gives confusion like findall with predicate function gives error.